# How to supply crediential.json file implicitly?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I need to authenticate my python code via **credentials.json** (*implicitly*).
It is working fine when i am mentioning my *crediential.json* file locally (inside folder).

- **But i need like:** I don't want to present(*crediential.json*) locally.
- It have to be present remotely either in GCP secrete manager or in  GCP cloud storage or any other storage repos.

***My Working code :***

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'C:\Users\testfolder\crediential.json'
```

***i need like:***

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_of_GCP_secrete_manager or path_of_GCP_cloud_storage or path_of_any_other_storage_repos'
```

ple suggest how can we achieve this or Is there any other way to achieve this.

***EDIT***-

***Here is my CODE***

```
import csv
import os
import json

from google.cloud import asset_v1, servicemanagement_v1, service_usage_v1
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime

credential_path = r"C:\Users\testfolder\credentials.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

from google.cloud import asset_v1


client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()
response = client.search_all_iam_policies(
    request={"scope": "projects/1234567", "page_size": 1000}
)
for policy in response:
    print(policy)
```

1. When i run this it displaying the correct output (i.e) all IAM
   policies. --> here i have my credintial.json file locally.
2. **Need:** But I need to store this credential.json file remotely and need to fetch directly from remote. (Remote can be GCS or Sercret manager)
3. but I dont have idea, how to achive

Comment: Where is running your code and why do you need a service account key file?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere bro, i have edited & updated  my code and mentioned my need. plese have a look.  **Just I need to pass credientials.json remotly**

Comment: I don't understand the WHY you need that file stored remotely. Which service/plateform will use it? My concern in the following: If you need to access to secret manager or to Cloud Storage, you must be authenticated. If you need a service account key file to be authenticated, an need to be authenticated to get the service account key file, we are in a dead loop.

Comment: The best approach is to not use credentials.json at all. Use the service account attached to the service the code is running on. Lookup ADC (Application Default Credentials) for the service you are running on.

Comment: @John Hanley 

 Thanks Bro

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere thanks bro will work on it

Comment: @sudharchrome can you please let us know if the above comments help you?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty Yes, it is help full & now i can able to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting @John Hanley comment for better visibility:

The best way to achieve your goal is not to use `credentials.json` file at all. You should use service account attached to service the code is running on. Look for Application Default Credentials for this service.

Useful links:

- [ADC](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/)
- [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)
- [gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default)